# How to group by week even when the count is 0

Tags: sql-server, group-by, left-join

My below example works fine, the only challenge i am facing is that weeks with 0 results do not show.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
SELECT 
DATENAME (WK, DATE) AS WEEK,
COUNT (DISTINCT COMPANY_ID) AS AMOUNT
FROM
(
SELECT COMPANY, DATE = MIN(DATE)
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE YEAR(A.DATE) = '2019' AND COMPANY_ID NOT IN(SELECT COMPANY_ID  FROM 
TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B  ON A.ID = B.ID AND DATE < '2019-01-01') GROUP 
BY COMPANY_ID) d    

GROUP BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0),  DATENAME(WK, DATE) 
ORDER BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0)
```

My current output looks like this:

```
week      | amount
4        |  354
6        |  222
7        |  144
8        |  354
9        |  45
10       |  55
11       |  76
12       |  98
13       |  45
14       |  344
```

The result above is missing many weeks (1,2,3 and 15,16,17 etc.)
How do i get to show those with 0 count?

My desired output:

```
week     | amount
1        |  0
2        |  0
3        |  0
4        |  354
6        |  222
7        |  144
8        |  354
9        |  45
10       |  55
11       |  76
12       |  98
13       |  45
14       |  344
15       |  0
16       |  0
17       |  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note -

1) Your current query is not correct (Possibly, you have removed some portion of it to hide confidential stuff).
Ex. In the subquery named "d", the `GROUP BY` is on "company_id" column but "company" has been `SELECT`-ed.

```
SELECT  DATENAME (WK, DATE) AS WEEK,
    COUNT (DISTINCT COMPANY_ID) AS AMOUNT
FROM    
(
    SELECT COMPANY /*Different from group_by clause*/, DATE = MIN(DATE)
    FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON (A.ID = B.ID)
    WHERE   YEAR(A.DATE) = '2019' 
        AND COMPANY_ID NOT IN 
        (   
            SELECT COMPANY_ID
            FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND DATE < '2019-01-01'
        ) 
    GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
) d    
GROUP BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0),  DATENAME(WK, DATE) 
ORDER BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0)
```

2) I hope while editing you have not remove any clauses mistakenly.

3) Could you please post some input data to understand the output better.

(Apologies for posting here, as I don't have privilege to comment.)

Answer (score 0):

First Create a temp table that has all weeks numbers

then join it with your query

```
DECLARE @Weeks AS Table(ID int)

DECLARE @i int = 1


WHILE @i < 53
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Weeks (ID)
VALUES(@i)
SET @i = @i  + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Weeks


SELECT 
DATENAME (WK, DATE) AS WEEK,
COUNT (DISTINCT COMPANY_ID) AS AMOUNT
FROM
(
SELECT COMPANY, DATE = MIN(DATE)
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @Weeks W ON W.ID = DATENAME (WK, DATE) 
WHERE YEAR(A.DATE) = '2019' AND COMPANY_ID NOT IN(SELECT COMPANY_ID  FROM 
TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B  ON A.ID = B.ID AND DATE < '2019-01-01') GROUP 
BY COMPANY_ID) d    

GROUP BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0),  DATENAME(WK, DATE) 
ORDER BY dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, DATE), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried your query and it seems to be running for a very long time 2 min+
Not sure if the temp table is making everything so slow

Comment: @MishMish that will depends on your table